# Converting VTK UnstructuredGrid to StructuredGrid

Tags: python, vtk, paraview, simpleitk

The background to my problem is that I have a 3D structure saved in a .vtk file that I need to manipulate (dilate, erode, etc.). The following code snippets are designed to be run sequentially, i.e. if you run them one after the other, there should be no problems (apart from those I mention!).

I'm very new to VTK, so apologies for any very basic mistakes!

## Problem

My problem stems from a problem with SimpleITK, wherein it is unable to read UnstructuredGrid or PolyData:

```
In [1]: import SimpleITK as sitk
In [2]: img_vtk = sitk.ReadImage(file_vtk)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-52-435ce999db50>", line 1, in <module>
    img_vtk = sitk.ReadImage(file_vtk)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/SimpleITK/SimpleITK.py", line 8614, in ReadImage
    return _SimpleITK.ReadImage(*args)

RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK ReadImage: /tmp/SimpleITK/Code/IO/src/sitkImageReaderBase.cxx:97:
sitk::ERROR: Unable to determine ImageIO reader for "/data/ROMPA_MRIandSeg/09S/Analysis/1_model/clip_dilate.vtk"
```

SimpleITK can, however, read StructuredGrid, so I tried to solve this by reading using VTK and converting.

```
import vtk
reader = vtk.vtkGenericDataObjectReader() # Using generic to allow it to match either Unstructured or PolyData
reader.SetFileName(file_vtk)
reader.Update()
output = reader.GetOutput()
```

However, from that point on, every method I've tried seems to have failed.

## Proposed Solutions

### Conversion to numpy, then conversion to sitk image

I attempted to convert it to a numpy array (), then interpolate a regular grid, with a dummy variable of 1 to specify the values on the structure.

```
from vtk.utils import numpy_support
import scipy.interpolate
import numpy as np

nparray = numpy_support.vtk_to_numpy(output.GetPointData().GetArray(0))

output_bounds = output.GetBounds()
x_grid = range(math.floor(output_bounds[0]),math.ceil(output_bounds[1]),1)
y_grid = range(math.floor(output_bounds[2]),math.ceil(output_bounds[3]),1)
z_grid = range(math.floor(output_bounds[4]),math.ceil(output_bounds[5]),1)
grid = list()
for x in x_grid:
   for y in y_grid:
      for z in z_grid:
         grid.append((x,y,z))
dummy = np.array([1 for i in range(nparray.shape[0])])
npgrid = scipy.interpolate.griddata(nparray,dummy,grid,fill_value=0)

npgrid.reshape(len(x_grid),len(y_grid),len(z_grid))
img = sitk.GetImageFromArray(npgrid)
sitk.WriteImage(img,file_out)
```

However, when I load this in ParaView, a bounding box is displayed for the output, but a contour of the output is empty.

### Using `ShepardMethod`

I attempted to interpolate using the built-in `ShepardMethod`, after converting the UnstructuredGrid to PolyData (as I'd mostly seen ShepardMethod being applied to PolyData):

```
bounds = output.GetBounds()
spacings = [1.0,1.0,1.0] # arbitrary spacing
dimensions = [0,0,0]
for i,spacing in enumerate(spacings):
    dimensions[i] = int(math.ceil((bounds[i*2 + 1]-bounds[i*2])/spacing))

vtkPoints = vtk.vtkPoints()
for i in range(0,nparray.shape[0]):
   x=nparray[i,0]
   y=nparray[i,1]
   z=nparray[i,2]
   p=[x,y,z]
   vtkPoints.InsertNextPoint(p)
poly = vtk.vtkPolyData()
poly.SetPoints(vtkPoints)    

shepard = vtk.vtkShepardMethod()
shepard.SetInputData(poly)
shepard.SetSampleDimensions(dimensions)
shepard.SetModelBounds(output.GetBounds())
shepard.Update()
shepard_data = shepard.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetArray(0)

shepard_numpy = numpy_support.vtk_to_numpy(shepard_data)
shepard_numpy = shepard_numpy.reshape(dimensions[0],dimensions[1],dimensions[2])
shepard_img = sitk.GetImageFromArray(shepard_numpy)
sitk.WriteImage(shepard_img,file_out)
```

As with the numpy effort above, this provided a bounding box in ParaView. Applying a contour provided a structure of two triangles, i.e. next to nothing seems to have been successfully written. Alternatively, I attempted to write the output directly using VTK.

```
shepard_data = shepard.GetOutput()
shepard_grid = vtk.vtkImageToStructuredGrid()
shepard_grid.SetInputData(shepard_data)
shepard_grid.Update()

writer = vtk.vtkStructuredGridWriter()
writer.SetFileName(file_out)
writer.SetInputData(shepard_grid.GetOutput())
writer.Write()
```

This produced the same output as before.

### Using `ProbeFilter`

I tried the above using `ProbeFilter` instead (with both conversion to `numpy` and writing directly). Unfortunately, the output was the same as above.

```
mesh = vtk.vtkStructuredGrid()
mesh.SetDimensions(dimensions)

probe = vtk.vtkProbeFilter()
probe.SetInputData(mesh)
probe.SetSourceData(output)
probe.Update()
probe_out = probe.GetOutput()

writer = vtk.vtkStructuredGridWriter()
writer.SetFileName(file_out)
writer.SetInputData(probe.GetOutput())
writer.Write()

probe_data = probe.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetArray(0)
probe_numpy = numpy_support.vtk_to_numpy(probe_data)
probe_numpy = probe_numpy.reshape(dimensions[0],dimensions[1],dimensions[2])
probe_img = sitk.GetImageFromArray(probe_numpy)
```

sitk.WriteImage(probe_img,file_out)

However, this seemed to produce no viable output (`vtkStructuredGridWriter` produced an empty file, and `probe_numpy` was empty).

### Changing ParaView output

My original data comes from a structuredGrid .vtk file, that I open using ParaView, and then clip to remove structures that aren't required in the mesh. Saving the output saves an unstructuredGrid, and I have been unable to figure out whether I can change that, and avoid this mess in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

Just use "Resample With Dataset" filter in ParaView.

- Open ParaView
- Open a StructuredGrid file file with the geometry you want it to have
- Open your UnstructuredGrid file
- Add a "Resample with dataset" filter
- Select structured data as source input
- Apply

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea. Unfortunately (for reasons entirely beyond my understanding), the ResampleWithDataset1 output is empty (the Data Ranges are all zero). This is after selecting the unstructured polydata as input, and the structured grid as source.

Comment: Can you share data samples ?

Comment: The clipped data is here (http://www.filedropper.com/clipdilate), and the unclipped original is here (http://www.filedropper.com/dilate). Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure of what you want to do. your clipdilate.vtk is a complex polydata. Storing that in a structured grid will definitelly lose some structural data. What do you want to do with this data after that ?

Comment: Sorry for not replying - was forced to progress without solving this, and unable to look back on this thread until now.

Subsequent steps with these data involve code written in Matlab and C++, which are designed to take data from structured grids - it'll be nigh on impossible to reformat the subsequent code. Under normal circumstances, changing from polydata to structured grid would lose structural data, but since the original data are structured grid, any change should be marginal.

Thanks again!